# How to use the ORM for the equivalent of a SQL count, group and join query?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have tags which can be associated with images and locations.

- Tags are unique.
- Images and locations can have many tags.
- A Tag_Item model is used to link everything together.

Here are the models:

```
LOCATIONS = (
    ('US', 'USA'),
    ('UK', 'United Kingdom'),
    ('FR', 'France'),
)

class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(choices=LOCATIONS)

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image')

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

class Tag_Item(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to write a query which means **select the five most frequent tags for USA**.

I was thinking something along the following lines in SQL:

- Join Tag, Tag_Item, and Location where location is 'US'.
- Group it by tag.
- Order it by a count of Tag_ID (or something along those lines).

but I can't figure out how to transfer that in Django ORM.

Can you please help me on how to write that sort of complex relationship queries?

Comment: Take a look at annotation and aggregation https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Hey, @TomBrock I was wondering, did you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a few things to begin a query like this:

- [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset), will be used to perform and add the count field.
- [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), will be used to order the queryset.
- [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), will be used to retrieve a specific column of the table.
- Notes on `GROUP BY ... COUNT`:
  [How to execute a GROUP BY ... COUNT or SUM in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm/45547675#45547675)
- You can get the related field of a foreign key  with the [`__` notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180190/django-using-objects-values-and-get-foreignkey-data-in-template).

---

You can simplify your described query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

usa_tags = Tag_Item.objects.filter(location__location='US')
                           .values('tag__tag__id')
                           .annotate(my_count=Count('tag__tag__id')
                           .order_by('my_count')
```

That will return an ordered dictionary who's 1st entry is the top tag 2nd entry is the second tag in use etc. :

```
tag_id | my_count
-------|---------
   5   |   101
   1   |    53
  ...  |   ...
```

Now you can retrieve the five top tags from that dictionary.