# QuerySet group by several fields django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do a query and I want to group by several fields. Some of those fields are foreign keys. When I get my query set back, I would like those foreign keys to be objects of their respective models. The only way I have found to group by a queryset is `values('model1', 'model2', 'somefield')`. When I do this, though, the values I get from those fields are the IDs of those objects.

What I'm looking for is an equivalent query set to this:

`SELECT model1, model2, somefield, sum(something) FROM table WHERE (conditions here) GROUP BY model1, model2, somefield`

And I would like `model1`, `model2` to actually be model objects instead of just IDs.

Any good way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this partial solution may be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181936/843999

Answer (score 0):

When you use a regular Django model query:

```
model_instances = Model.objects.filter(some condition).order_by('model1', 'model2', 'some_field')
```

`model_instance` gets an array of instances of class `Model`, and every instance's foreign key attributes are also instances of corresponding models, so `model_instances[0].model1` would be an instance of 'Model1'.

You can check Django reference for making queries [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't group by those models. It just orders by them. I would like to emulate `GROUP BY` in SQL. I know that I can do it with `values()` but that returns DB values instead of model instances.

Comment: Oh! In that case you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: Same problem as the one I mentioned in my previous comment. I have done some research and found that they just do not have a good way to do `GROUP BY`. Oh well! Thanks for the help.